# How to sum values in multidimensional dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Normally I would use sum(dict['A'].values()) in order to sum all the values in a dictionary with the key "A". However in this case it is not all the  values of the "main" key I want to sum, but rather all the values where the "secondary/sub-key" has a specific name. Let me show a simplified example below:

```
dict = {'A':{'val1':3,'val2':5},'B':{'val1':2,'val2':6}}
sum1 = dict['A']['val1']+dict['B']['val1']
sum2 = dict['A']['val2']+dict['B']['val2']
```

The example above is fairly easy since it's only a 2*2 dimension, and thus I can fairly easily add the values directly. But this method is not practical when the dictionary gets larger. So I wonder what is the most efficient solution.

Comment: what should be the result for this dict `{'A':{'val5': 1,'val1':3,'val2':5},'B':{'val3':2,'val2':6, 'val1': 10}}` ?

Comment: Do you want to print only the values under dict['A'] or the sum of all the values of the dictionary ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum nested key values of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345539/sum-nested-key-values-of-dict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum values for a single subkey you could use `sum()` with a generator expression:

```
>>> d = {'A': {'val1': 3,'val2': 5}, 'B': {'val1': 2, 'val2': 6}}
>>> sum(x['val1'] for x in d.values())
5
```

To sum values for *all* subkeys you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter())
>>> dict(counter)
{'val2': 11, 'val1': 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the keys of your dict and retrieve the values to add them to a variable.

So you would start by declaring the `sum` variables where you will store the sums, and iterate through every key in your dict to add the corresponding values to the `sum` variables. You could also easily add more values in the future by adding `val3` and `sum3`, `val4` and `sum4`, etc. Here is an example:

```
my_dict = {'A':{'val1':3,'val2':5},'B':{'val1':2,'val2':6}}

# initiate variables to store the sums
sum1, sum2 = (0,) * 2

# iterate through the keys of your dict and increment the sum variables
for key in my_dict:
    sum1 += my_dict[key]['val1']
    sum2 += my_dict[key]['val2']

print(sum1)
print(sum2)
```

This prints:

```
5
11
```

Also, as @jpp mentioned, never name a variable after a class, so don't name your dictionnary `dict` e.g. you can name it `my_dict`

Comment: Two points. **Never** name your dictionary after a class, e.g. use `my_dict` instead of `dict`. Second point, why not iterate `for key in my_dict: ... ` ? `iterkeys` is not required to iterate keys.

Comment: @jpp I am aware of the naming convention, I simply copied the code in the question. But I do agree with your second point, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {'A':{'val1':3,'val2':5},'B':{'val1':2,'val2':6}}
>>> sum((Counter(d[x]) for x in d), Counter())
Counter({'val2': 11, 'val1': 5})
```

Also note that you shouldn't name your dictionary as `dict`. It shadows the built-in [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-dict) function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this easily readable and understandable solution, which iterates over each key/value pair to update a new dictionary with the sum of values, whatever the size of input dictionaries. I also renamed the input dictionary into `d` instead of `dict` because `dict` is the name of the Python built-in class:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'A':{'val1':3,'val2':5},'B':{'val1':2,'val2':6}}

sumDict = defaultdict(int)

for v1 in d.values():
    for k2,v2 in v1.items():
        sumDict[k2] += v2

print(dict(sumDict))    # {'val1': 5, 'val2': 11}
print(sumDict['val1'])  # 5
print(sumDict['val2'])  # 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store sum of the every element inside the dict in a new dictionary

```
dict = {'A':{'val1':3,'val2':5},'B':{'val1':2,'val2':7}}
sums = {}
sum = 0
for element in dict:
    for key in dict[element]:
        sum += dict[element][key]
    sums[element] = sum
    sum = 0
print(sums['A']) # 8
print(sums['B']) # 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the union of relevant keys. Then use a dictionary comprehension to construct a dictionary mapping these keys to their sums:

```
d = {'A':{'val1':3,'val2':5},'B':{'val1':2,'val2':6}}

sum_keys = set().union(*d.values())
sums = {k: sum(d[i].get(k, 0) for i in d) for k in sum_keys}

print(sums)

{'val1': 5, 'val2': 11}
```